# how to cancel highlight in Mac OS emacs

Tags: emacs, osx-mavericks

[image: Emacs highlighting problem]

I realize it might be not an interesting question, but does anyone know how to cancel the highlighting area (shown in the yellow) in Emacs24.

I first selected that area and entered M-w (I meant to copy that area), then the highlighting shows up. The behavior seems quite mysterious to me since most of the time M-w works fine. Can anyone shed some light on why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think you select the area by `C-SPC`, you could press `C-SPC` again to unselect them. If this doesn't work, you could press `C-g` to quit(I think the highlight will disappear). If all do not work as expected, you could press `ESC ESC ESC`, I think this could help you out.